# Insert TypoScript Object into HMENU

Tags: typo3, typoscript

TYPO3 v 7.6.13
Indexed_search 7.6.0

I’m generating a typical drop menu using TYPOScript.

And I’m appending a list item at the end that contains a drop menu for a search box.

I’m using indexed_search and I have a separate Typoscript Oject setup called lib.search.

In my typoscript that generates my drop down menu, how can I reference / insert lib.search and have it inserted into my drop down menu.

This is my search TS,

```
lib.mainNavi = HMENU
lib.mainNavi.wrap (

<div class="navbar navbar_custom" role="navigation" aria-label="Main Navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">|<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicons glyphicons-search" data-toggle="dropdown"></a><ul class="dropdown-menu col-md-12 col-xs-12 dropdown_grd"><li>
    <input type="text" class="searchText" placeholder="Search for..."/>
    <input type="button" class="searchButton" id="navSearchButton"/>

**search TSO goes here{lib.searchheader}**

</li></ul></li></ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>

  )
```

And this is the TS that generates my search box.

```
lib.searchheader = COA_INT
lib.searchheader {
  10 = TEXT
  10.typolink.parameter = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.searchUID}
  10.typolink.returnLast = url
  10.wrap = <ul><li>|</li></ul>
}
```

When I reference lib.search I only get text when the page is rendered:

```
{lib.searchheader}
```

Comment: what do you expect? that a fluid-variable like text in a wrap will be replaced automagically with some other typoscript object? don't mix up fluid and typoscript so they depend on each other. maybe your question misses the exact problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want another TS-object to be inserted at a special position, enable your TS to insert something there.
Either you use a wrap or you can use a COA.

in your example the wrap is way to big and you can't wrap two different contents. so my attempt would be to split up your wrap in a COA:

```
lib.mainNavi = COA
lib.mainNavi {
    wrap = <div class="navbar navbar_custom" role="navigation" aria-label="Main Navigation"> | </div>

    // intro
    10 = TEXT
    10.value (
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
        </div>
     )

     //outer-wrap of menu
     20 = COA
     20 {
         wrap ( 
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 |
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
         )

         // the real menu    
         10 = HMENU
         10 {
            :
         }

         // additional search entry:
         20 = COA
         20 {
            wrap (  
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicons glyphicons-search" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu col-md-12 col-xs-12 dropdown_grd">
                     <li>
                        <input type="text" class="searchText" placeholder="Search for..."/>
                        <input type="button" class="searchButton" id="navSearchButton"/>
                        |
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            )

            10 < lib.searchheader      
         }
     }     
 }
```

And be careful mixing USER and USER_INT objects. (never cascade USER_INT inside USER_INT)
Those uncached objects are stored with a placeholder similar to a fluid-variable with a hash-name. They will be evaluted/resolved at run time.

are you sure your `lib.searchheader` needs to be an COA_INT?